# What is the linguistic name for sentence with "even though"?

Tags: linguistics

What is the specific name for a sentence that contains the words "even though"?

Comment: If you are sure that such a word exists, that would be worth mentioning.  Also, I believe you are concerned about the *phrase* "even though," not the *words*; for example: "The number zero is even, though that may not be the number you had in mind."

Answer (score 1):

"Even though" is a subordinating conjunction, which introduces a dependent clause.